# Running 'iconv' command for a file passed as function arguments in C++ application

Tags: c++, string, io

I am trying to convert a Windows file (CP1252 format) into a UTF-8 format for a Linux application. 
I want to run the following command as part of my C++ application:

`iconv -f CP1252 -t UTF-8 file.ldf |dos2unix > out.ldf`

The filename `file.ldf` will be passed as an argument to the `main()`.

eg.

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string FileName = "Invalid";
    if (argc == 2) {
        FileName = argv[1];
        system("iconv -f CP1252 -t UTF-8 file.ldf |dos2unix > out.ldf");
        //do further parsing on file                        
    }
    else
        cout << "ERROR:: invalid number of arguments"<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem I am facing currently is to pass the incoming `filename` as part of the command to be executed using the `system` API.
Is there any other way in which this problem can be tackled?

Comment: You *do* know you can append strings using the `+` operator? Like e.g. `"iconv -f CP1252 -t UTF-8 " + FileName + "  | dos2unix > out.ldf"`

Comment: aargh!! I realise now that's a silly question indeed. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
system("iconv -f CP1252 -t UTF-8 file.ldf |dos2unix > out.ldf");
```

to this:

```
system("iconv -f CP1252 -t UTF-8 " + FileName + " |dos2unix > out.ldf");
```

where I used the overloaded `+` operator of [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/), for string concatenation.