# Inconsistency with running command 'iconv' through commandline vs C++ application

Tags: c++, bash, shell, popen, file-conversion

I am trying to convert a windows file CP1252 format into UTF-8 format for parsing in a C++ application. 
I use the following command :

```
iconv -f CP1252 -t UTF-8 file.ldf |dos2unix > out.ldf
```

When I try running the same command in a C++ application using :

```
system("iconv -f CP1252 -t UTF-8 file.ldf |dos2unix > out.ldf");
```

some of the characters are not encoded properly. 
For eg. the German characters `ü, ö, ä` are encoded as `ï¿½`

I understand that the operator `>` is a shell feature and I think using it in a C++ operation causes this discrepancy.

I have also tried using `popen("iconv -f CP1252 -t UTF-8 file.ldf |dos2unix > out.ldf", "r");` but to no success.

Is there any other way to redirect the conversion to `out.ldf` without using the `>` operator in a C++ application.

EDIT: the question linked to be as duplicate is a completely different problem as to one addressed here.

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string FileName = "Invalid";
    if (argc == 2) {
        FileName = argv[1];
        system("iconv -f CP1252 -t UTF-8" + FileName + "|dos2unix > out.ldf");
        //system("iconv -f CP1252 -t UTF-8 file.ldf |dos2unix > out.ldf");
        //do further parsing on file                        
    }
    else
        cout << "ERROR:: invalid number of arguments"<< endl;
    return 0;
}


//file.ldf -- windows file (CP1252 format)
physical_value, 0, 254, 0.5, -20, "�C";

//out.ldf -- after conversion using 'iconv' command on the command line
physical_value, 0, 254, 0.5, -20, "üC";

//out.ldf -- after conversion using the 'system' API
physical_value, 0, 254, 0.5, -20, "ï¿½C";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running 'iconv' command for a file passed as function arguments in C++ application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46239685/running-iconv-command-for-a-file-passed-as-function-arguments-in-c-applicati)

Comment: @NathanOliver @user0042 : though the questions are asked by the same OP, the problem addressed in both the questions are different. The former one was related to the usage of `system()` API and this one corresponds to the file encoding .

Comment: Make sure the iconv programs you are running are the same ones.  The command window may or may not have a different path that when you do a system command from C++.  As a test, hard code the full path name of the iconv program in your system command.

Comment: No, you cannot possibly be running the same command in a C++ application using "system(iconv -f CP1252 -t UTF-8 file.ldf |dos2unix > out.ldf);". That won't even compile, obviously. If you have a problem with real code, then your question should include real code, as a [mcve]. The only thing that can result from fake code is fake answers.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik : I don't understand your point. I do not have any issues with the compilation.  The file `out.ldf` is generated as well but with the following characters `ï¿½` for `ü` . All other characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9) are outputted correctly to the file `out.ldf`, except the special characters, mentioned in the question

Comment: The point that if you have a problem with real code, then you need to show it, as a [mcve]. Posting fake code, and then fixing the obvious syntax error after it's been pointed out, is not a substitute for a [mcve]. Just because a C++ compiles doesn't mean that it will work correctly, which is why a [mcve] is required. Review stackoverflow.com's [help] article that explains how to create a [mcve], then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Looks like you missed a plus sign after Filename.

Comment: @AnonMail : corrected